# How to show output in webapp directlt at form1 C#

Tags: c#

I want to print values at bottom of Form1 directly. It is a web app so if I 
write `Console.WriteLine("Something");` it doesn't make sense or doesn't print out any thing at Form1. How can I print in Form1 directly?

[image]

Comment: Just drop a Label on the form1 and do Label.Text = "Something";

Comment: Are you incapable of adding another label..?

Comment: @ inquisitive_mind  I can do that "Number, Average and Is heavy" are written in that method already .but I want to show user output simultaneously with a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pictorial sequence for printing the word "Something" on a web form (on your browser):

[image: Step 1: create new project]

[image: Step 2: Click OK to accept defaults]

[image: Step 3: OK again]

Right-click on the blue highlighted WebApplication2.

[image: Step 4: create new webform]

[image: Step 5: OK it]

A webform will appear:

[image: Step 6: Click on this button]

[image: Step 7: Create new label]

Press F7 key to go to the webform code page.

[image: Step 8: Write code, then compile]

Then look at your resulting browser page.

**UPDATE:**

Oh, so you want to write to a winform instead of a webform.  Use this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Something";
        }
    }
}
```

Then,

1. Put your mouse on `label1`, right-click, choose "View Designer".
2. In the properties box, go to the "Text" property.
3. To the right of the property, type "Click here" to replace "Label1".
4. Hit return.
5. Then run it.

Comment: Label label5 = new Label();
           label5.Text = "Something";
           this.Controls.Add(label5);
That result I was want

Comment: Thanks It wil help me a lot

Comment: Yes, that's another way to do the same thing.  Please upvote me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a ASP.NET Web Forms and want to add controls directly to the HTML via code behind.

Look into UserControls for a more proper way moving forward. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx

But to answer your question directly, the quick and dirty is below.

Within the aspx file create a PlaceHolder

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phMain" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In the code behind you can add HTML directly to the PlaceHolder

```
phMain.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span>Hello!</span>"));
```

### Update

I see you added a picture of a WinForm app after you said Web App. In that case you should try a ListView https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx